# Drag Drop Picturebox

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, picturebox

I am trying to make an application in which i have 7 Pictureboxes and i want to drag drop one each time i click then move the mouse on the form. I did make it to some extend by moving the picture-box on the form but i cannot keep the original image. When i drag drop a picture box i want to drag drop just a copy not the whole picture box on the form. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Kind regards.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        controller = Controller.getController();
        InitializeComponent();
        this.AllowDrop = true;
        this.pbOR.MouseDown += pbOR_MouseUp;

    }
    private void pbOR_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        downPoint = e.Location;
        pbOR.Parent = this;
        pbOR.BringToFront();
    }

    private void pbOR_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            pbOR.Left += e.X - downPoint.X;
            pbOR.Top += e.Y - downPoint.Y;
        }
    }

    private void pbOR_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Control c = GetChildAtPoint(new Point(pbOR.Left - 1, pbOR.Top));
        if (c == null) c = this;
        Point newLoc = c.PointToClient(pbOR.Parent.PointToScreen(pbOR.Location));
        pbOR.Parent = c;
        pbOR.Location = newLoc;
    }
```

Comment: So you want to copy image from one picturebox to another using dragdrop ?

Comment: It's not clear whether you want to create an entirely new PictureBox when dragging or whether you just want to start dragging from one PictureBox and drop on another PictureBox to copy the image.

Comment: i have one picturebox which when i drag it  i want to make a copy  of the picture on the location i drop but not the same picturebox, i want to keep the picturebox on the same location and just drag drop out copies of it. Kind regards